# Cropping the exact same part of several pictures

Tags: pixelmator

I have several pictures that are exactly the same except for some small variations. It was one picture that was *photoshopped* in several different ways. Now, I need to crop them all (13 in total) but I need to crop exactly the same part of it. It needs to be pixel perfect.

How do I do that with Pixelmator?

Comment: I would suggest using Photoshop actions if you have access to Photoshop. I don't think Pixelmator has something equivalent. Can you use a 3rd party program like Reformator? You can try the program with a trial.

Comment: Another program you could use is [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up performing this by using the command line program mogrify that comes with ImageMagick:

```
mogrify -verbose -crop 2700x1519+2300+550 *.jpg
```