# Bulk croping same portion from multiple file

Tags: gimp, crop, linux

I want to crop same portion, say rectangular areas from multiple image files which are located at same place in all files. Is there anyway to do it in GIMP? and I also have to do it regularly. Can I save a template for this action.

I've read [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46737/cropping-the-exact-same-part-of-several-pictures) .I don't know if it is the same problem or not

Comment: The question you point to has the right answer.

Comment: I can't flag it as duplicate. Somebody may do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Batch Image Manipulation Plugin (BIMP) for GIMP which could be used to make crops to every image in a folder. However, it has limitations on positioning of the crop, e.g. centre, top left, bottom right, etc. [You can find it here](https://github.com/alessandrofrancesconi/gimp-plugin-bimp/releases/tag/v2.0). I have no link or affiliation with the developer, and I don't know how to install it on Linux, although I found a [link here](https://www.fosslinux.com/1207/bimp-adds-batch-processing-of-images-power-to-gimp.htm) which might be useful.

If you need to set a custom positioned crop, then perhaps have a look at using ImageMagick (which is free). There's a [tutorial on batch cropping here](https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/04/30/batch-crop-images-with-imagemagick/). I have no link or affiliation with that website.

In case of link rot, the example ImageMagick command given in that tutorial is

```
mogrify -crop 300x300+150+150 -path ./cropped *.png
```

This would crop all PNG images contained in a folder to x=300px by y=300px at position x=150px, y=150px and save the results in a folder named "cropped".

Comment: "I have no link or affiliation...." is is any rule in this stackexchange or your habit to repeat this. 

Comment: @IbnFulan It's not a rule as such. I just prefer to make it absolutely clear when linking to other sites whether I am affiliated to them or not. It helps avoid being accused of spamming. It's not that you aren't allowed to link to your own website, but you should make it clear if you do.

Comment: I see. That's a good practice.